# Bottom Sheet hide the toolbar bottom icons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-sheet

I would like to know if there is any way with the  bottom sheet  SWIFTUI to build an app layout like Image Below, where a bottom sheet is displayed behind of a toolbar.

[I want this Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMWFp.jpg)

I tried to achieved it but didn't.
ISSUE[A bottom sheet is displayed on top of a toolbar].

XCODE 14.0.1

CODE:

`

```
struct Track1: View {
   
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack() {
               .toolbar {
                   
**# MY BOTTOM TOOL BAR IS HERE **
                    ToolbarItem(placement:.bottomBar)
                    {
                        HStack(spacing:11){

 Button{}label: {
VStack
{ 
Image(icon: .home_g)
                                        .renderingMode(.template)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
 Text("Home")  

}
.frame(width: 65, height:  65)
.cornerRadius(25)

                            }    }  }
                
  GeometryReader{
              geo in
                
        MapView(mapType: .standard,showsUserLocation: true)
                    
                       
                
**# 
# MY BOTTOM SHEET IS HERE **
                        .sheet(isPresented: $shopListVM.showSheet) {
                                                   ZStack{
                                                       if #available(iOS 16, *) {
                                                           VStack{
                                                              Text("SHEET IS OPEN")
                                                           }




                                                           .presentationDetents([.medium, .fraction(0.1)])

                                                         }
                                                               else {
                                                             VStack{
                                                                 Text("SHEET IS OPEN")
                                                             }
                                                         }
                                                   }




                                                           }
                    
                    VStack(spacing:20){
                        
                       
                            VStack{
                                HStack{
                                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                                    TextField("Search..",text: $searchText)
      }
                           
       .padding()
                                    
       .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .padding(.top,30)
         .padding(.horizontal,30)
                            }

                      
                    
                       
                    }
                       
                
                       
                    
            
   
                }
         
            }
            .accentColor(Color(hex: 0xFA6109))
         
        }
    }
}
```

`

[Image-Issue remain unsolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfk8j.jpg)

Comment: You may want to consider paring this down to a [mre] and formatting your code.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks for feedback, now check actual code ,Basically I want to separate my bottom toolbar with bottom sheet function(like describe in the 1st image)  ,I have faced problem when applying .toolbar{} with .sheet() function, when bottom sheet appeared,it hide the toolbar bottom buttons. Kindly see the attachments below the above post.